# Aggregate text keys-values python defaultdict

Tags: python, text, python-2.7

First of all, I would like to point out that I am a python newbie and I am totally inexperienced at coding, so please be patient. I've already searched for an answer to my problem but with no success.
I have a bunch of lines in text with names and teams in this format:

```
Team (year)|Surname1, Name1
```

e.g.

```
Yankees (1993)|Abbot, Jim
Yankees (1994)|Abbot, Jim
Yankees (1993)|Assenmacher, Paul
Yankees (2000)|Buddies, Mike
Yankees (2000)|Canseco, Jose
```

and so on for several years and several teams.
I would like to aggregate names of players according to team (year) combination deleting any duplicated names (it may happen that in the original database there is some redundant information). In the example, my output should be:

```
Yankees (1993)|Abbot, Jim, Assenmacher, Paul
Yankees (1994)|Abbot, Jim
Yankees (2000)|Buddies, Mike, Canseco, Jose
```

I've written this code so far:

```
file_in = open('filein.txt')
file_out = open('fileout.txt', 'w+')

from collections import defaultdict
teams = defaultdict(set)

for line in file_in:
    items = [line.split('|')]
    team = items[0]
    name = items[1]
    teams[team].add(name)
```

I end up with a big dictionary made up by keys (the name of the team and the year) and sets of values. But I don't know exactly how to go on to aggregate things.

I would also be able to compare my final sets of values (e.g. how many players have Yankee's team of 1993 and 1994 in common?). How can I do this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please don't post the same question again and again.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411998/python-aggregate-keys-and-values-defaultdict and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405541/aggregate-sets-according-to-keys-with-defaultdict-python.

Comment: I've deleted it and edited. How is it possible that is still present?

Comment: People with 10k+ rep can view deleted question, so don't try to act smart.

Comment: Well I'm sorry...I didn't mean to bother and I didn't know about the viewing policy.

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregate things"? It looks like the dictionary you have is exactly what you wanted?

Comment: I guess I need a way to print my final sets in separate lines in a file, according to the keys, but I have no idea on how to do that...

Comment: @jterrace : I've tried something like this at the end: for key in teams.iteritems():
print "{}|{}".format(team,"|",name)   ....but it gives me an error saying: name = items[1] and IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this line:

```
items = [line.split('|')]
```

should have been:

```
items = line.split('|')
```

Otherwise, it was creating a list made up of a list.

---

Second, I changed this:

```
teams[team].add(name)
```

to this:

```
teams[team].add(name.strip())
```

Otherwise, you'd get extra newlines and spaces in the player name.

---

The full modified read code:

```
for line in file_in:
    items = line.split('|')
    team = items[0]
    name = items[1]
    teams[team].add(name.strip())
```

To print the dictionary out after:

```
>>> for team, players in teams.iteritems():
...    print '{}|{}'.format(team, '|'.join(players))
... 
Yankees (1994)|Abbot, Jim
Yankees (1993)|Assenmacher, Paul|Abbot, Jim
Yankees (2000)|Canseco, Jose|Buddies, Mike
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted to do...

Answer (score 0):

For this case you should get familiar with Map-Reduce, research a little about it and that will help you, I'm sure I have some code around here and I'm trying to find it, in the meantime this is a good place to start: 
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

this solution is not optimal, but it works the way you want it to:

```
for line in w.split('\n'):
    items = line.split('|')
    team = items[0]
    names = items[1].split(',')
    if team in teams:
       teams[team].extend(names)
    else:
       teams[team] = names
```

from there you could use:

```
for team, names in teams.iteritems():
    print team, len(set(names))
```